# batch command to use findstr with parameterised path

Tags: batch-file

How do I use a parameterised path in `findstr` to find some text and get it?

I have used the below command but unfortunately it is not working. wheather it is able to find the text from  file from a same path.

this code is working:

```
@echo off
findstr /m "boy" A.txt 
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo Found! >log.txt
)
if %errorlevel%==1  (
  echo No matches found >log.txt
)
```

This is not working:

```
set target_path = \\C:\Users\ayanjit\Desktop\New folder 

findstr /m "boy" %target_path%\A.txt 
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo Found! >log.txt
)
if %errorlevel%==1  (
  echo No matches found >log.txt
)
```

Answer (score 2):

SPACES are significant in a `SET` command. You are setting the value of the environment variable `"target_path "` but using the environment variable `"target_path"`. Since *that* variable is not set, you are looking in the file `\A.txt`

Next problem is that since the full-filename you want contains spaces, you need to look for `"%target_path\A.txt"` - where the quotes are REQUIRED. That's after you assign the variable to `target_path` of course.

Answer (score 1):

`\\C:\...` isn't valid syntax. Use either `C:\...` for a local path, or `\\hostname\share\...` for a remote path. Also, as [Peter Wright](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17495788/1630171) pointed out, there shouldn't be spaces around the `=` sign in variable assignments:

```
set "var=value"
```

as opposed to

```
set var = value
```

and you should put double quotes around any path with spaces in it (including variables holding such paths).

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
set "target_path=C:\Users\ayanjit\Desktop\New folder" 

findstr /m "boy" "%target_path%\A.txt"
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  >log.txt echo Found! 
) else (
  >log.txt echo No matches found 
)
```